# React Native release build crashed is iOS specific modules in package.json

Tags: react-native

Have developed an app in RN and not sure if this is a problem in the RN build process or an ID10T error on my part.

One of the views needed to be able to add events to the device calendar, and none of the modules I could find online were cross-platform, so there was an Android and an iOS specific module for each.

When working in dev mode everything is perfect, but as soon as a build a release version the app crashes on load, and after a lot of testing I determined it to be simply that this non-Android package was listing in the package.json.

The package dev was not able to help, but at the same time I cannot imagine it is the package itself that is causing anything wrong, there are no references to it anywhere within any of the android files, the buttons are only loaded if the device is iOS and they are not on the initial screen.

Is this a flaw int he RN build process or is there some additional config/exclusions I need to setup.

Other than adding new modules into the required locations for android/xcode the setups are pretty much as I got them out of the box and as best as my google fu reveals nobody seems to of reported this issue before

For interest the iOS calendar module is https://github.com/wmcmahan/react-native-calendar-events.

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of problems are very common when developing applications with the node ecosystem

> this non-Android package was listing in the package.json

and

> there are no references to it anywhere within any of the android files, the buttons are only loaded if the device is iOS and they are not on the initial screen

Looks like you are not looking in the right place or searching the right way.

Standing in the project root
`fgrep -rlo "string literal" . | grep -v "ios"` replace "string literal" with the module that is being loaded in the wrong platform and you will find all occurrences of this string in the files.

If this doesn't help you find your issue, there are lots of things you can try but you will have to provide more code.